# PhpStorm MySQL use DB undefined

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpstorm

- Laravel version 5.5.20
- IDE: PhpStorm

Here is my code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use DB;

class TasksController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $users = DB::select('select * from users where active = ?', [1]);

        return view('tasks.index', ['users' => $users]);
    }
}
?>
```

At line 5 IDE shows "Undefined class DB", and line 11 doesn't work too.

I tried to change line 5 to `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;` but line 11 still don't work, it says

> Method 'select' not found in Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB

I check my `config\app.php`, aliases already have `'DB' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class`

I change "use DB" to "Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB",it works!
BUT the Phpstorm still draw underline error at select statement,
and says "mathod select not found in Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB"
is there any way to ignore that eror on Phpstorm IDE tool ?

Comment: See https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2015/01/laravel-development-using-phpstorm/

Comment: Have you checked whtat's it returning in $users?

Comment: `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;` is what must be used -- works just fine here. Try restarting web server/kill PHP process -- sometimes it still runs old code (does not see new one).

Comment: You may also try `File | Invalidate Caches...` and restart IDE if that message "Method 'select' not found in..." continues to show up in PhpStorm.

Comment: Even though not related, the closing ?> tag must be omitted from files containing only PHP, according to PSR standards ;)

Comment: After I change to use    Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;  and restarting web server & Invalidate Caches, shows    Illuminate\Database\QueryException;    could not find driver (SQL: 'select * from users where active  = 1')

Comment: @GretaJames BTW -- do you have Laravel IDE Helper installed and run? https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper -- its a must have for coding Laravel in PhpStorm -- it will provide code completion etc (from IDE side, of course)

Comment: @GretaJames *"shows Illuminate\Database\QueryException; could not find driver"* What DB engine do you use? By default it's MySQL. Do you have corresponding PHP extension enabled (`php_pdo_mysql` for MySQL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function index()
{
    $users = \DB::table('users')->where('active', 1)->get();

    return view('tasks.index', ['users' => $users]);
}
```

or

```
public function index()
{
    $users = \DB::raw('select * from users where active = ?', [1]);

    return view('tasks.index', ['users' => $users]);
}
```